# Why Atlas Textures increase the 2D game performance?

Tags: optimization, unity-game-engine, textures

Atlas Textures waste many pixels because images in an atlas have different sizes.

For example two images: `1024x10` pixels and `400x400` pixels in a same atlas waste too many pixels.

Is it better that I define 2 different Textures instead of one Atlas Texture?

Answer (score 2):

In Unity, a large number of materials and objects in your scene means potentially bad performance/framerate.  The more materials you have, the more draw calls you have.  Here's a great explanation:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/14578/whats-the-best-way-to-reduce-draw-calls.html

Also see:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html

You want to use as few materials as possible in your scene.  This will enable Unity to use only 1 draw call for each of your gameobjects that share the same material.  So in order to make different objects share the same material, you will have to combine the textures into an atlas, so that they can share the same texture.  You just have to arrange the textures in your atlas to save as much space as possible.

Of course if you only have a few models, it's pointless to make an atlas since it won't be making a significant impact on your performance anyway.